# XAML style for flashing

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I create style for buttons:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#8A88E1"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ff0000"/>                    
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

It all OK. Now i want to create style that would be forced to blink when you hover the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using a trigger and storyboard:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="0:0:0.2"
                            From="White" To="Red" RepeatBehavior="3x" AutoReverse="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```